# How to press CTRL+T and CTRL+TAB in selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

> Hi All,
>
> For one of my project I need to open a new tab and navigate between
>   the tabs for the same I need to know how can I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> in Selenium Webdriver using Java.
>
> Please let me know how can I do the same.Thank You...!!!
>
> **I'm using the below:**
>
> **Firefox Version:** 48.0.2
>
> **Java Version:** 1.8
>
> **Selenium WebDriver Version:** 3.0.0
>
> **OS:** Windows 10

**I tried the below code but it doesn't seems to be working:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Handling_Tabs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"t");
        driver.get("http://www.bing.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"\t");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actions class for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. I modified your example as shown below

```
@Test
public void OpeningNewTab(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    driver.get("http://www.bing.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();

}
```

Comment: The above code is not working for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes. I have tested first and then put it here.What is the error you are getting ? please paste here as comment. You can introduce Thread.sleep() or WebDriverWait inbetween steps to introduce some waiting time.

Comment: One query : Why you are using geckodriver.exe ? Is there any specific reason behind that ? I have used "selenium server 2.53" and default firefox browser.

Comment: If you are using Selenium 3 then to work with Firefox browser you need to use separate a driver in this case Firefox Gecko Driver same the way we use for IE and chrome browsers which will interact with Firefox browser. I'm using slenium Version 3.0.0 with Mozilla version 48.0.2.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Robot class as well simply import

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Keyboard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                    Robot robot = new Robot();

       // Simulate a mouse click
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

      // ctrl + T & ctrl TAB  

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);

                // CTRL+T is now pressed 

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

            } catch (AWTException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @VishvambruthJT  Put some wait and check again its working fine.

Comment: I'm able to open the new tab using the below code but unable to open URL on the new tab how to movethe control to new tab: try {
Robot robot = new Robot();
// CTRL+T is now pressed 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);            
            //Release pressed CTRL+T  
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);      
     }catch (AWTException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.get("http://www.bing.com/");

Comment: Do not use Robot