# Using sendKeys command for "multiple, simultaneous key press" actions in JMeter WebDriver sampler

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am trying to perform a multi key press action on Guidewire applications using JMeter WebDriver. Find the below samples

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

I guess Selenium allows key press only for special and function keys

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Action class might help you.

```
Actions keypress= new Actions(driver); 
Action seriesOfActions = keypress
   .keyDown(webelement, Keys.SHIFT) 
   .keyDown(webelement, Keys.ALT+T) 
    .build(); 
   SeriesOfActions.perform();
```

options 2 is to use Robot class:
[How to press CTRL+T and CTRL+TAB in selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338773/how-to-press-ctrlt-and-ctrltab-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Actions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) and [Keys.chord](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#chord-java.lang.CharSequence...-) combination like:

```
var keys = org.openqa.selenium.Keys
new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(WDS.browser).sendKeys(keys .chord(keys .ALT, keys .SHIFT, "P")).build().perform()
```

More information on WebDriver sampler tips and tricks: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)